# Удалить повторяющиеся элементы списка по свойству. C#

Tags: c#, list, compare

Есть список объектов

```
List<TableCellCombinedParameterData> table2 = new List<TableCellCombinedParameterData>();
```

У каждого элемента в этом списке есть свойство `Id`.
Как удалить элементы из списка, у который одинаковый параметр `Id`?.

Я решил таким способом, но мне кажется есть вариант по-лучше)

```
            int flag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < table2.Count; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < table3.Count; j++) 
                {
                    if (table2[i].ParamId != table3[j].ParamId) 
                    {
                        flag++;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == table3.Count)
                {
                    table3.Add(table2[i]);
                }
                flag=0;

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью LINQ, группируем по ID и берем первые элементы в группах.

```
var results = table2.GroupBy(x => x.ParamId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```